# Aria role attribute in angular2

Tags: html, angular, wai-aria, angular4-forms

I find it odd that ARIA role attribute does not seem to be working - atleast for me - in Angular 2. I tried giving a div role="listbox" and defined the children as role="option" and still it does not seem to work.

Can someone help me out here?

```
    <div>
    <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="listbox" tabindex="0" id="listbox1"  [attr.aria-activedescendant]="listbox1-1">
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-1" class="selected">Green</div>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-2">Orange</div>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-3">Red</div>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-4">Blue</div>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-5">Violet</div>
    <div [attr.aria-role]="option" id="listbox1-6">Periwinkle</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the plunker -    https://plnkr.co/edit/Pex56Ou3BRInPCfoh6mX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you pass anything in attribute binding(`[]`), then attribute value evaluate with component context, that means when `attr.aria-role` value tries to evaluate, it check `option` value inside component context(`this`) which `undefined`(not defined), hence you don't see attribute on DOM.

So either put `option` variable inside your component with `'option'` value. Or you could directly use below

```
[attr.aria-role]="'option'"
```

**OR**

```
aria-role="option"
```

[**Forked Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/uhawjTyAhMxRdXNTaFCz?p=preview)